# Pass stored procedure parameter values to nested stored procedure without knowing parameter names

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a universal error trapping stored procedure that is called within all stored procedures and I need to get all parameter names (I can do this from system tables just knowing stored procedure name) and values.

The values is what I really need to obtain and get them dynamically (without having to specifically pass them to the stored procedure by name).

Is there some way to pass a unique ID or some other thing to a nested stored procedure that I can use to get the parameter values for main stored procedure in nested stored procedure?

Short example: I have a stored procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE testParamaters
    @text1 VARCHAR(500),
    @DateTime1 DATETIME
AS

-- I want to be able to call an SP something like this:
EXEC DynamicErrorTrackingSP (pass something, system variable/data/etc, so I can 
                             dynamically get all parameter values in nested SP)
```

I currently have code similar to this and it works fine (but it will have to be edited for every SP to correctly pass the parameter values (I do not want to have to edit it for every SP).

```
EXEC DynamicErrorTrackingSP @ParmaterNameValuePairs = 
     '@text1 = ' + @text1 + ', @DateTime1 = ' + cast(@DateTime1 as varchar(500)) + ''
```

Comment: Check the info about [Information_Schema.Routines](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx) and [Information_Schema.Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173796.aspx)

Comment: The above 2 links are things I already know (and I am using) but I need to know how to get the parameter values as well as parameter names (which I can get)

Comment: The values are run-time variable, I don't think there is a way to get them outside the current stored procedure run without passing them.

Comment: Is there anyway to send a full collection of the variables name/value pair without having to specifically call out each variable and name to the procedure I am sending it to?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
Only if someone find a way to get a variable value from it's name.

**Answer**
It is possible to create a new data type of type table and use it as the input of the error tracking stored procedure. In that variable there will be a row for each parameter with the name and the value.
An example of this is

```
CREATE TYPE _stored_param AS TABLE (
  Name varchar(50)
, [Value] sql_Variant
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE printParam (@sentParam _stored_param READONLY) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM @sentParam
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure (@param VARCHAR(10)) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @myParam AS _stored_param;

  INSERT INTO @myParam (Name, [Value]) VALUES ('@param', @param)
  EXEC printParam @myParam;
END
GO

EXEC myProcedure 'foo'
```

The result of the execution of myProcedure, done last line will get you

```
Name    Value
------- -------
@param  foo
```

Cool! ... but the `INSERT` is static, and every time a stored procedure parameter is changed or added the `INSERT` need to be changed as well.

We can change the procedure to create a dynamic `INSERT`, using the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS` to get the parameters name using `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)` in the `WHERE` condition to get only the one for the current procedure.

***An inception SP***

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Inception (@param1 VARCHAR(10), @param2 INT)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @paramQuery as NVARCHAR(MAX);
  DECLARE @paramVar as _stored_param;
  DECLARE @execVar as NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @paramQuery = '';
  SELECT   @paramQuery 
        += 'SELECT ''' + PARAMETER_NAME 
         + ''', CAST(' + PARAMETER_NAME + ' AS SQL_VARIANT) UNION ALL '
  FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
  WHERE    SPECIFIC_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
  ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

  SET @paramQuery = LEFT(@paramQuery, len(@paramQuery) - 10);

  SET @execVar = ''
  SELECT   @execVar 
        += PARAMETER_NAME + ' ' + DATA_TYPE 
         + ISNULL('(' + CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR) + '), ', ', ')
  FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
  WHERE    SPECIFIC_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
  ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

  SET @execVar = LEFT(@execVar, LEN(@execVar) - 1);

  INSERT INTO @paramVar
  EXEC sp_executesql @paramQuery, @execVar, @param1, @param2

  SELECT * from @paramVar
END
GO

EXEC Inception 'foo', 2;
```

Within this stored procedure the variable `@paramQuery` is evaluated to the string

```
SELECT '@param1', CAST(@param1 AS SQL_VARIANT) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT '@param2', CAST(@param2 AS SQL_VARIANT)
```

but as a dynamic query it need to be executed.

Executing a dynamic query is like calling another stored procedure: you need to pass the parameter when needed and the execution is on an isolated level with is own local parameter where the caller variable are not visible.
That means that to execute the query to get the parameters values you need to pass the parameters values as parameters.
The only advantage is that when the stored procedure is altered changing the parameter number the query will generate an error like

```
Msg 8178, Level 16, State 1, Line 39
The parameterized query '(@param1 varchar(10), @param2 int)SELECT '@param1', CAST(@param1' expects the parameter '@param2', which was not supplied.
```

asking to check the `sp_executesql` parameter passage.

Other method like creating a string with the name and value of the parameter or creating a XML with the name and value of the parameter will hit the same wall: get the value of a variable given his name as a string (varchar).